# Excel adds Values when I copy and paste headings in Powerpoint Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I use Excel from Powerpoint to insert data, and I want to copy the Column headings, Excel adds an extra value - see below
Dec - 13     Jan - 14    Feb - 14    Dec - 132   Jan - 143   Feb - 144   Dec - 133   Jan - 144   Feb - 145
80% 72% 71% 41% 12% 13% 92% 91% 89%
91% 87% 83% 45% 71% 65% 81% 53% 53%
3%  6%  5%

I have change Cell Format to TEXT.
I have tried to Paste Values - does not work.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean when you use powerpoint to insert data? How are you moving the data? The data you've supplied is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint, go to the Insert tab and open the drop-down menu under the "Table" button (see screenshot).

[image]

The last item on that menu is "Excel Spreadsheet." This will add a small Excel workbook in a floating, resizable window. You can paste data from another workbook in there without losing any of the formatting.

[image]